# TFS 2010: Wrong Build Agent is chosen

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-agent

I have two configured Build Agents on one Controller:

1. **Default Agent**
2. **Default Agent1**

I defined a build definition with the following Agent Settings:

```
Maximum Agent Execution Time:        00:00:00
Maximum Agent Reservation Wait Time: 04:00:00
Name Filter:                         Default Agent
Tag Comparison Operator:             MatchExactly
Tags Filter:
```

I created some **BuildInformation Activities** **after** the GetAgent Activity.

1. `String.Format("Build Agentname: {0}", BuildAgent.Name)`
2. `String.Format("AgentSettingsName: {0}; AgentSettingsTags: {1}", AgentSettings.Name, String.Join(",", AgentSettings.Tags))`

The Output is:

```
AgentScope (reserved build agent Default Agent1)
Build Agentname: Default Agent1
AgentSettingsName: Default Agent; AgentSettingsTags:
```

So the `AgentSettings.Name` argument is set to "Default Agent", but paradoxically "Default Agent 1" is used.

Workflow:
[image]

The strange thing is that sometimes the right Build Agent is chosen.

Is this a bug? What is my mistake?

It would be nice if someone could reproduce this behaviour too.

EDIT:

I have created an error feedback: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/725885/tfs-2010-wrong-build-agent-is-choosen

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like a bug if you are using the `AgentScope` activity.  Have you logged in on the [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) site?

Be sure you are using the [AgentScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_AgentScope) activity instead of the [GetBuildAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_GetBuildAgent) activity.  I couldn't tell which one you were referring to from your question.  The `AgentScope` activity is the one that actually reserves the agent based on the agent reservation specifications parameter details that you specify.

Comment: I have updated my question. I use both AgentScope and GetBuildAgent.

Answer (score 0):

When we provide the **Name Filter = Default agent**.  It takes whichever agent is available and continue with that agent.
If you want to choose any specific agent you can use a simple assign activity just after get the build agent to choose the specific build agent as used below.

agentsettings.name= "Agent name".

This will let you choose that build agent you wanted it to perform the task.

OR

You can use the functionality of **tags** in the build agent and use **agentsettings.hastags**.